# NPM package - relaying information to the consumer

Tags: javascript

- I'm writing a NPM package.
- The package wants to pass logging information to the consumer, about non-fatal errors and whatnot.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

- `console.log` is a bad solution, because the consumer doesn't necessarily want to hear everything our package's saying
- `console.log` with a verbosity setting sounds a bit better, but perhaps the consumer wants our package to speak somewhere else, rather than to the console
- The best solution I can think of currently is exposing a callback for the entire module, which gets called every time our package has something to say, perhaps along with a verbosity setting. The consumer can either console.log it, pass to his own logger, or do whatever else he pleases.

However, I haven't seen the third approach anywhere yet, and most packages seem to be just blatantly console.logging

What's the best approach here?